# Pushy APNS: No route to host

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, pushy

I am trying to send iOS push notifications using the [Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy) Java library.  The code to send the APNS looks like this:

```
String topic = "XXX";
        ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder().setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
                .setClientCredentials(new File(
                        "apns_a5400831-a2db-480b-9487-52cfe61fc4f0.p12"),
                        "Password123!")
                .build();
        ApnsPayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = new SimpleApnsPayloadBuilder();
        String payload = payloadBuilder.buildMdmPayload(magic);
        String sanitizedToken = TokenUtil.sanitizeTokenString(deviceToken);

        try {
            SimpleApnsPushNotification pushNotification = new SimpleApnsPushNotification(sanitizedToken, topic,
                    payload);
            PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushNotificationResponse = apnsClient
                    .sendNotification(pushNotification).get();

            if (pushNotificationResponse.isAccepted()) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("testCheckin(String, String) - {}", "Push notification accepted by APNs gateway."); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                }
            } else {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("testCheckin(String, String) - {}", //$NON-NLS-1$
                            "Notification rejected by the APNs gateway: " //$NON-NLS-1$
                                    + pushNotificationResponse.getRejectionReason());
                }

                pushNotificationResponse.getTokenInvalidationTimestamp().ifPresent(timestamp -> {
                    System.out.println("\t…and the token is invalid as of " + timestamp);
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("testCheckin(String, String) - exception ignored", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
```

Much of this is taken straight from the documentation.  When I run the code, though, I get the following Exception:

```
15:55:58 WARN  [com.eatthepath.pushy.apns.ApnsChannelPool] Failed to create channel: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$SearchDomainUnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'api.sandbox.push.apple.com' and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [lan]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:467)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:256)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.onQueryWriteCompletion(DnsQueryContext.java:193)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.access$200(DnsQueryContext.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$3.operationComplete(DnsQueryContext.java:185)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$3.operationComplete(DnsQueryContext.java:182)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeFail(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:723)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:288)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:967)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.flush(AbstractChannel.java:254)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.flushQueries(DnsNameResolver.java:1257)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.internalResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:361)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.doSearchDomainQuery(DnsResolveContext.java:284)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolveContext.doSearchDomainQuery(DnsAddressResolveContext.java:96)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.resolve(DnsResolveContext.java:249)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAllUncached0(DnsNameResolver.java:1158)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAllUncached(DnsNameResolver.java:1131)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:1080)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:1048)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolveAll(SimpleNameResolver.java:79)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolve(InflightNameResolver.java:96)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolveAll(InflightNameResolver.java:71)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolveAll(InflightNameResolver.java:56)
    at io.netty.resolver.RoundRobinInetAddressResolver.doResolve(RoundRobinInetAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:162)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:116)
    at com.eatthepath.pushy.apns.ApnsChannelFactory.lambda$create$3(ApnsChannelFactory.java:175)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverException: [/[2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8844]:53] failed to send a query via UDP (no stack trace available)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:901)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:863)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:821)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.doWriteMessage(NioDatagramChannel.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:143)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:967)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.flush(AbstractChannel.java:254)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.flushQueries(DnsNameResolver.java:1257)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.internalResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:361)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.doSearchDomainQuery(DnsResolveContext.java:284)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolveContext.doSearchDomainQuery(DnsAddressResolveContext.java:96)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.resolve(DnsResolveContext.java:249)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAllUncached0(DnsNameResolver.java:1158)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAllUncached(DnsNameResolver.java:1131)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:1080)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:1048)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolveAll(SimpleNameResolver.java:79)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolve(InflightNameResolver.java:96)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolveAll(InflightNameResolver.java:71)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.InflightNameResolver.resolveAll(InflightNameResolver.java:56)
    at io.netty.resolver.RoundRobinInetAddressResolver.doResolve(RoundRobinInetAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:162)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:116)
    at com.eatthepath.pushy.apns.ApnsChannelFactory.lambda$create$3(ApnsChannelFactory.java:175)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a different Java APNS library I should be using?

Comment: Can you please share which version of Pushy library you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception  you get

**"io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverException: [/[2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8844]:53] failed to send a query via UDP (no stack trace available)"**,

it seems that you are attempting to use IPv6 but your network probably is not supporting it. Try to force IPv4 preference with the following system property.

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true.
```